# Regex for time-zones, special case being ignored

Tags: python, regex

I am creating a regex to parse a string of time zones. The output must be reading input in the following form:

- 0930
- 0930+10930-1
- <0930
- (>0930) (the brackets are just to avoid stack reading this as '<>')
- (<0920+1)
- (>0920+1)
- 0920-1240 +1
- 1200-1-1430
- 1200-1-1400+1
- 0920-1240 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<***ISSUE HERE***

The regex cannot differentiate between hhmm-1, and hhmm-hhmm. It will read '0900-1200' as '0900-1'.

I have attempted many variateions of the regex, including:

```
r'([<>])?([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([+-]?)([0-1]?)|([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})'

r'([<>])?([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([+-])?([0-1]?)(([0-1]?{4})()'

r'([<>])?([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([+-])?([0-1]?)(?([0-1]?)()'
```

Currently just considering using 2 different ones! One to test for case of hyphenated time string, the other for the rest,which work for me.
I would like the output in a list of tuples, like

```
[('', '09', '30', '-', '','12','30', '-', '1'),
 ('', '09', '30', '-', '1','','', '', ''),
 ('>', '09', '30', '-', '1','','', '', '').....]
```

Comment: Does `r'([<>])?([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(?:([+-])([01])(?!\d{3}\b))?'` help?

Comment: hmm it does directly parse it Wiktor! However, I would like it seperated into more groups, so instead of 0930-1230 having 0930 in one tuple and 1230 in the next tuple, I want it all in one tuple! so I think the tuple would be length 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
([<>])?([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(?:([+-])([01])(?!\d{3}\b))?(?:([+-])([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(?:([+-])([01])(?!\d{3}\b))?)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0a2BS4/1). *Details*:

- `([<>])?` - Group 1 (optional): `<` or `>`
- `([0-9]{2})` - Group 2: two digits
- `([0-9]{2})` - Group 3: two digits
- `(?:([+-])([01])(?!\d{3}\b))?` - an optional group matching a sequence of:

  - `([+-])` - Group 4: `+` or `-`
  - `([01])(?!\d{3}\b)` - Group 5: `1` or `0` that are not followed with 3 more digits followed with a word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `([+-])` - Group 6: `+` or `-`
  - `([0-9]{2})` - Group 7: two digits
  - `([0-9]{2})` - Group 8: two digits
  - `(?:([+-])([01])(?!\d{3}\b))?` - Optional sequence of `+` or `-` captured in Group 9 and then `1` or `0` (captured in Group 10) that are not followed with 3 more digits followed with a word boundary
- `)?` - end of non-capturing group, repeat 1 or 0 times.